# Add a custom field to email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added a custom field to the checkout page on WooCommerce.
I am wondering how to add this field into the order email.

This is the code I use to add a select field to the checkout page:

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['Plaats'] = array(
    'label'       => __('Plaats', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder' => _x('Wij bezorgen alleen in Hoofddorp', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'    => true,
    'clear'       => false,
    'type'        => 'select',
    'slug'        => 'Plaats',
    'options'     => array(
        'option_a' => __('Hoofddorp', 'woocommerce' ),
        'option_b' => __('Nieuw-Vennep', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    );
}
```

I want to add one of the options to the email ( option_a or option_b).

I also tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
/**
* Add the field to order emails
**/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys');

function my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
$keys[] = 'Plaats';
return $keys; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `after_woocommerce_pay` hook functions to save your data in the database, use this function: `add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);` to save your info attached to a shop_order post. Now you can get the info from de database and add to the email.

Use: `$meta_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );` to get the info from data base and use the hook `woocommerce_email_order_meta` to put the info yo need in order email.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing here is an underscore before `Plaats`

Replace

```
/**
* Add the field to order emails
**/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 
'my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys');

function my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
$keys[] = 'Plaats';
return $keys; 
}
```

With

```
/**
* Add the field to order emails
**/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 
'my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys');

function my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
$keys[] = '_Plaats';
return $keys; 
}
```

Goes in your child theme's function.php. Tested and works on WooCommerce 3.7